# Атрибут Pattern в INPUT, HTML

Tags: html, атрибуты

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы в поле `<INPUT>` можно было вводить только латинские слова верхнего и нижнего реестра, и чтобы можно было писать Цифры, но когда ввел `<input name="login" id="name" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]" maxleght="16" minleght="4" />` при попытке отправить форму пишет `Пожалуйста, используйте требуемый формат`, подскажите как это исправить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно написать вот так и все сработает:

```
<input name="login" id="name" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{4,16}" />
```